# Is is possible to use the || operator within junit tests of java code?

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to write a junit test that compares two arrayList's. My problem is that when I create one arrayList from getting information from my program, the information is returned in different orders because it is stored in an unordered structure. So for example, I might get "a or b" one time, and "b or a" the next.

When I talked to my professor about this, he said it was possible to set up a junit test using an || operator so the data returned would match either "a or b" or "b or a". I've looked for use of the or operator with junit tests online, but have been unable to find any. If this is indeed possible, could someone provide the proper format? Thanks!

Comment: Not enough info.  It's not at all clear what you mean by "a or b" vs "b or a".  Are you saying that the returned List contains elements in the order a-b but the reference data is in the order b-a?

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following in an assertion:

```
assertTrue((result == a) || (result == b));
```

That allows you to test if your result is either a or b.

Answer (score 2):

You probably could do this, but don't.

Unit tests should be deterministic — the test operation should always emit the same output every time. So or statements in unit tests are a code smell.

It seems like what you really care about is that a and b are both in the list. If that's all you really care about, then testing for order is a stronger assertion than you need — which can be just as bad as a weaker one.

Try reorganizing things so that you can do this:

```
assertTrue(theList.contains(a));
assertTrue(theList.contains(b));
```

Comment: Yeah, this works most of the time.  But it doesn't work if there are repeated elements.  So if the list has to be some ordering of `a, a, b`, then this will incorrectly return true if the list is actually `b, b, a`.

Comment: In that case, you might want to just build another list that has the required elements in the right order, and than use `.equals`. You may also want to refactor your application code so that it's easier to test.

Comment: sounds like you're describing the answer I posted earlier

Comment: @David: sounds like you're karma-whoring ;-). But, seriously, I would put a lot more emphasis on the second half of the response. When things get to the point where you have to build a list in a test just to evaluate the app code's response, it's probably time to refactor.

Answer (score 2):

This is where the Hamcrest collection matchers become very useful.

You can use

```
assertThat(theList, containsInAnyOrder(a, b))
```

This perform the check that you're after, is clean, concise, readable code, and also provides a rich description when the assertion fails.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement this assertion like so:

```
public void assertEqualsUnordered(Collection<?> a, Collection<?> b) {
  assertEquals(a.size(), b.size());
  List<Object> aCopy = new ArrayList<Object>(a);
  for(Object o : b) {
    assertTrue(aCopy.remove(o));
    // fails if this object wasn't present in aCopy,
    // but if it succeeds, removes one of "o" from aCopy
  }
}
```

This should work on any collections, be they lists, sets, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like

```
Collections.sort( theList );
assertEquals( expectedList, theList );
```

where `expectedList` has the right elements, sorted in the natural order.